# Run MSI / exe file from any web browser

Tags: asp.net-mvc, windows-installer, webbrowser-control

I have created an MSI / exe file using Visual Studio Installer. I want to run this installer from a web browser.

The purpose for doing this is that one of my client wants to perform a digital signature, the private key token of which is stored in the USB attached to the client machine.
As the USB can't be accessed from the browser due to security reasons (restricted access), I am trying to create a windows form installer app, which opens from any browser application (made in say MVC etc.), accesses the private key, and returns the encrypted string back to the browser from the windows app.

So my primary questions are:
1.) How to run the installer from the web browser. If installer already installed, how to check for newer versions?

2.) How to pass a string from web app to the windows form app

3.) How to return the modified string from windows form app back to the same web browser application

So any suggestions / recommendations / approach you can guide me through.

Thanks In Advance!!!..

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to make it work.

Let's say you created a windows application for the clients and the name of the application is "AwesomeApp"

If you want to launch the application from the browser then you need to write an HTML href tag like this

```
<a href="AwesomeApp://<input arguments>" role="button" class="btn btn-primary">
Launch AwesomeApp</a>
```

When a user clicks on this button, the browser is going to ask to open your application. If the user clicks on "yes" then your application will be launched with input arguments

Now let's move to another part of the problem, how can you open a browser from your windows application

Definitely, you cannot talk back to the same tab that you opened in the browser. What you can do is that you can launch the browser with a specific string appended with your main Url.
Launching browser totally depends on what language you are using to develop windows application.

I guess you will be able to achieve what you wanted from this.

Comment: Hey thanks for the inputs. I will trying your solution. Just have some questions:
1.) Will this application open from any web browser?.
2.) How the values should be passed in the input arguments
3.) How to check if the application is already installed or not. If not open the installer, and if yes, check for updates (if any).